# how to delete formatting when copy pasting in microsoft word from internet

Tags: microsoft-word

Here is a small error I am getting.
While I copy pasted name of a book and its link some formatting from website remained.
I tried to delete it but it was of no help.
Here is how it looks.[image: microsoft word error of format]
If you see I circled the small circle at bottom of page that come as I clicked on the tool below design 
that I marked in red.The thing is this formatting is not going when I press delete button.
How can I get rid of this.

Comment: I don't understand "I circled the small circle at bottom of page that come as I clicked on the tool below design that I marked in red" but just paste your text into notepad first, and paste into Word from there.

Comment: yes that is a trick I understand but in case some goof up has happened then is there a way to do it using word only I usually do what you mentioned in notepad and then paste

Comment: You may clean the formats as PicantePixel replied in first paragraph. The symbol ¤ looks like an end mark, could you put the cursor before this symbol? And is the Layout tab shown on ribbon? If is, please click Convert to Text  in Data group, then the symbol could be replaced by removable symbols.

Answer (score 1):

When you right-click in Word to paste, select keep text only to strip the formatting out. Or you can paste it into a program that doesn't have formatting options like Notepad and then paste it into Word (like what Alex M said).

This format looks like a cell marker. Can you not highlight it and hit delete, or right-click and delete it?

¤ This is the end-of-cell marker. It is a little like the paragraph mark in that it contains paragraph formatting for the last (or only) paragraph in the cell, but it also holds formatting for the cell. The same mark at the end of each row is the (wait for it) end-of-row marker, which serves a similar purpose with regard to row formatting.